# Alarm setting after re boot

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, alarmmanager

I am following http://blog.blundell-apps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/ this post and I made my app. So I can set a alarm on a specific date and time. It works fine but once the phone is restarted then it will just go off. So I googled and come to know the BroadcastReceiver.

My receiver code is this

```
public class StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, NotifyService.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

I have this settings in my manifext

```
<service
            android:name=".ScheduleService"
            android:label="ScheduleService Manager" >
        <action android:name="com.example.myapp.ScheduleService" />
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".NotifyService"
            android:label="NotifyService Manager" >
        <action android:name="com.example.myapp.NotifyService" />
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.myapp.StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

And I have this permission also

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

My BroadcastReceiver is starting after re-boot. But notifactions never shows. any idea why ?

Thanks

PS : Very very  new to android :)

Comment: You actually have to set the alarm after the reboot.  Simply setting up the boot receiver isn't enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have to set the alarm after the reboot.  Simply setting up the boot receiver isn't enough.

You can see upcoming alarms from the adb shell like this:

```
adb shell dumpsys alarm
```